# LINQ to XML pairing up two nodes inside XML document to a list or dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, dictionary

I have a XML document that basically looks like this:

```
<Item>
  <ItemID>1234567890</ItemID>
   <ItemSpecifics>
    <NameValueList>
      <Name>Style</Name>
      <Value>mens</Value>
    </NameValueList>
    <NameValueList>
      <Name>UPC</Name>
      <Value>123456789</Value>
    </NameValueList>
   </ItemSpecifics>
</Item>
```

And the "Item" Node repeats itself throughout the XML document, having multiple ItemID values and UPC values..

What I would like to do here is to extract the ItemID value from each Item node and it's UPC value.. So the output would be something like this (a list or dictionary containing):

```
ItemID   UPC
1        598
2        2134
3        9999
```

And so on..

I have tried something like this:

```
var document = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var upcValues = document.Descendants("NameValueList")
                       .Where(pair => pair.Element("Name").Value == "UPC")
                       .Select(pair => pair.Element("Value").Value)
                       .DefaultIfEmpty("n/a");
```

But this doesn't really achieves what I want as I'm not really sure how to extract both ID and UPC value at the same time from document...

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Please format the XML - it's hard to see the structure with all the elements just lines up on the left hand side.

Comment: @JonSkeet my apologies, how do I do that? I have never used a XML format here before =( P.S. I've used the ctrl + K option to format it

Comment: Um, you add spaces. Formatting XML is no different to formatting code.

Comment: @JonSkeet is it better now ?

Comment: Yes, much, thanks.

Comment: You should still put more effort into formatting that sample document. We only need a couple of items, and no other irrelevant elements, but what you *do* present should be formatted clearly. Please bear in mind that the purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of high quality questions and answers.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes I understand that, and I will put more effort into it from now on. Btw. I'm receiving a "Sequence contains no matching element" error in the edited reply.

Comment: @JonSkeet could it be due to the fact that some Item Nodes may not contain ItemID or UPC value ?

Comment: Please edit the *current* question rather than just saying you'll do better next time. As for the other problem - that should be asked in a new question, after you've tried to fix it yourself. (What would you even want the behavior to be in that case?)

Comment: @JonSkeet How about now ? :D

Comment: No: 1) It's all indented further than it needs to be; 2) it's not a valid XML document due to all the extra unclosed `Item` elements; 3) there are a lot of irrelevant elements (GalleryURL etc). The idea is to get something which is *minimal* but *complete*.

Comment: @JonSkeet Edited again. Better now ?=D

Comment: @JonSkeet P.S. I didn't remove other Item nodes to indicate that there are multiple ones in the document like I stated in the question...

Comment: We're now back to it not being there at all. What would have been better would be a complete document with two complete items (to demonstrate that there's more than one, but still being a valid document).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start with `Item` as that's the root of each entry that you want in the end. You also need to provide the namespace of the elements, which is defaulted in the root element of the doc. So something like:

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents";

var upcValues = document
    .Descendants(ns + "Item")
    .ToDictionary(
        item => (string) item.Element(ns + "ItemID"),
        item => (string) item.Elements(ns + "NameValueList")
                             .Single(nvl => (string) nvl.Element(ns + "Name") == "UPC")
                             .Element(ns + "Value"));
```

The first lambda expression selects the key in the dictionary element, from the `ItemID` element. The second lambda expression selects the value in the dictionary element by finding the only `NameValueList` element with a `Name` element with a value of "NPC", then taking that `NameValueList`'s `Value` element value.

Comment: JonSkeet, thanks a lot for the reply, I'm still getting 0 results from this code  :/

Comment: @User987: Well without a complete sample document, it's hard to know what's wrong. Perhaps there's a default namespace that you haven't shown us? (This is why it's always a good idea to include a [mcve] in the question.)

Comment: JonSkeet, do you mean a node above Item node in hierarchy ?

Comment: @User987: I mean a complete XML document which is representative of your actual document - but a minimal version (e.g. two items). My guess is that the root XML element has `xmlns="..."` indicating a default namespace...

Comment: JonSkeet yes , one moment ill paste the entire document :)

Comment: @User987: You've pasted it in in a horrible fashion, as if from a browser... and it only shows a single `Item` element. You said that your actual document has many `Item` elements, which would suggest it can't be the root element. It's *really* hard to help when you're providing contradictory information.

Comment: JonSkeet, I've pasted the entire XML Document now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141422/discussion-between-user987-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: @User987: Right, and now that you've provided the *actual* document, the problem is exactly as I thought. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks alot for the edited reply Jon.  I'm receiving a "Sequence contains no matching element". Could it be due to the fact that some Item Nodes may not contain ItemID or UPC value ?

Comment: @User987: Yes, that would indeed cause a problem. (It would be the UPC one.) But Stack Overflow isn't designed to be an interactive debugging service. You should look into that problem separately - the question you asked had no indication that there might not be a UPC element.

Comment: Yes true, should I simply add a where statement before the "Single" method to rule out the missing ones?